# How to get messenger's page access token in botframework

Tags: botframework

I developed a facebook messenger chatbot , and I want to know is there any possible to get the page access token of messenger channel in botframework ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I assume you are talking about capturing the FacebookAccessToken in the FacebookController or in the main Dialog of the Bot. I would like to capture it in both places.

Answer (score 0):

The document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) shows how to connect a bot framework bot to facebook messenger. Specifically, you can do the following to get your page access token:

ON THE FACEBOOK MESSENGER DEV PAGE:

[image]

Comment: Thank you answer. But I have this knowledge. What I want to know is that after set the Page Access Token in the messenger channel, how can I get this token in botframework by C#.net ?

Comment: When you're configuring the facebook channel in the azure portal, there is a box for putting in the page access token.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I realize this is old, but I believe he is referring to capturing the FacebookAccessToken in the FacebookController or in the main Dialog of the Bot. I would like to capture it in both places. Do you know how to do that?